# Javascript: Run multiple functions using onChange

Tags: javascript

I have this Javascript/HTML snippet:

```js
var select = document.getElementById("selectMe");
function loadMe()
{
    select.onchange = updateMe;
}

function updateMe()
{
    alert("I am updated");
}

function updateMeToo()
{
    alert("I am updated too!");
}

function updateMeAlso()
{
    alert("I am also updated!");
}
loadMe();
```

```html
<select id="selectMe">
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>bar</option>
</select>
```

The above code works fine but,

**Question:**

How can I run multiple functions on the code's "select.onchange" part?
I tried something like this:

```
select.onchange = updateMe; updateMeToo; updateMeAlso;
```

And as expected, it doesn't work.
I want to stick with my code as possible.
I also searched for some related issues but nothing helped.

Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
select.onchange = function () { updateMe(), updateMeAlso(),updateMeToo() };
```

Comment: that was awesome! I was confused at the result then I noticed you used updateMeAlso() twice. Edited it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **addEventListener** to add as many functions as you want.

```
var select = document.getElementById("selectMe");

select.addEventListener("onchange", loadMe, false);
select.addEventListener("onchange", updateMe, false);
select.addEventListener("onchange", updateMeToo, false);
select.addEventListener("onchange", updateMeAlso, false);
```

The main benefit is that you can remove any of those functions (event listeners) at any time later in any sequence without impacting other listeners. Just make sure you use the same list of arguments as it was for adding listener.

```
select.removeEventListener("onchange", updateMeToo, false);
```

You can read more about that 'mystical' third argument (useCapture) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Of course this pattern doesn't work with anonymous/arrow functions, because you need a name (a pointer) of the function to unregister it later. 
Here is an example which **doesn't work**

```
// you can add anonymous function
select.addEventListener(
  "onchange",
  function () { updateMe(), updateMeAlso(),updateMeAlso() },
  false
);

// but you cannot remove anonymous function from event listeners
select.removeEventListener(
  "onchange",
  function () { updateMe(), updateMeAlso(),updateMeAlso() },
  false
);
```

Comment: Great info you got there! I will also try to play my codes with these.

Comment: My pleasure @Jorz

Answer (score 1):

```
select.setAttribute('onchange','updateMe(); updateMeToo(); updateMeAlso();');
```

is my usual practice, I know you already accepted an answer but this works just as fine.

Comment: You can easily put parameters using setAttribute versus addEventListener